# How do I uninstall stock music indicator?

Tags: wingpanel, indicator-sound

I've uninstalled the stock music player (noise, I believe), however the controls above the volume slider remain. How do I uninstall them?

I've tried dconf-editor but couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's just a matter of choosing the right player in the settings app.

Comment: Can you give more details on how this fixes the issue of the media controls still showing up in the sound dialog from the volume indicator when Noise is uninstalled? Does choosing a specific player makes them go away? Or do you mean that choosing another player links those medial controls to that app?